# Understanding the mismatches of osmnx polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am using osmnx version 0.14.1 . While I am making edge bearing histogram and polar plots, I see some difference as they don't seem similar. As an example in the image: As there are 30 bins in the histogram, each bin having 12 degrees, 0-12 degree have the street of (approx) 800. But in the polar rose, it shows more than 1500 in that direction. Why is that? It looks like the full polar plot is shifted 1 bin backwards. Is there any way to fix that? I am attaching my code and image below.

[image: polar plot]
[image: histogram]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from IPython.display import Image
from pprint import pprint
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import geopandas as gpd


G = ox.graph_from_place('Chattanooga,Tennessee,USA', network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G), node_size=0)
# calculate edge bearings and visualize their frequency
G = ox.add_edge_bearings(G)
bearings = pd.Series([data['bearing'] for u, v, k, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)])
ax = bearings.hist(bins=30, zorder=2, alpha=0.8)
xlim = ax.set_xlim(0, 360)
ax.set_title('Chattanooga street network edge bearings')
plt.show()
# polar plot
import numpy as np
n = 30
count, division = np.histogram(bearings, bins=[ang*360/n for ang in range(0,n+1)])
division = division[0:-1]
width =  2 * np.pi/n
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction('clockwise')
bars = ax.bar(division * np.pi/180 - width * 0.5 , count, width=width, bottom=0.0)
ax.set_title('Chattanooga street network edge bearings', y=1.1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @gboeing could you kindly please address this?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions. First, upgrade to the latest version of the package (v1.0.1 as of this writing). Second, use the sample code in this [demo notebook](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v1.0.1/notebooks/17-street-network-orientations.ipynb) for a proper polar histogram.